# Iterate through chunks of a (somewhat structured) file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, parsing, data-structures

I have a file containing the following *"structured"* text :

```
>some multiline-
>text
---
>in multiple chunks (this one for instance is the second of this sample)
---
>Their number, sizes and content are irregular
---
>they can't
>be known in
>advance
---
>And they'll contain pretty much any char whatsoever known or unknown in the universe
>like //\n/...
---
```

I'd like to be able to read them through a `for` loop (this is a strong preference) something in the line of

```bash
for chunk in $(someUnknownMagic --over content.file)
do
  echo "I'll do something with ${chunk}"
done
```

I'm pretty sure there is a simple answer but I can't use

- `IFS` : it's a list of single char separators
- `sed` *(to simplify my pattern `'\n---\n'` towards something smart)* + `IFS` : since I'd have to select a separator char that may arise in my chunks

So I'm out of ideas (but I'm sure there's options galore) ...

Answer (score 3):

> sed (to simplify my pattern '\n---\n' towards something smart) + IFS

Great! Insert a unique byte, zero byte below, to separate the chunks, then read them as a stream separated by that byte. With GNU sed:

```
sed -z 's/\n---\n/\x00/g' content.file |
while IFS= read -r -d '' chunk; do
   echo "$chunk"
done
```

Really, just iterate over lines and accumulate until `---` line is found, do you need sophisticated:

```
chunk=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
     if [[ line == '---' ]]; then
        echo "$chunk"
        chunk=""
     fi
     chunk+=$line$'\n'
done < content.file
```

Comment: Can you explain what this `\x00` is and how/why it may never be found anywhere in a file ?
Can you explain what's `IFS`'s value in this pipe-ed `while` and why it splits the way I would want it to.
Last : I know I could go with while+accumulator, I just want to know if there is a (somehow) more fluid way. Some sort of tool you specify patterns for line start and chunck end and it spits an array or something (whithout boilerplating your way to a while with accumulation)

Comment: `what this \x00 is` `\x00` represents a byte with all zeros. Docs a little bit bad. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html -> `\xxx Produces or matches a character whose hexadecimal ASCII value is xx. `.  `why it may never be found anywhere in a file` It may be in the file. A zero byte is highly unlikely to be in a file containing lines and text.

Comment: `Can you explain what's IFS's value` IFS is set and empty `why it splits the way I would want it to` `read -d ''` read the input up until a zero byte. Setting `IFS` to empty disables `read` feature of word splitting the input. Without it ... the input would have leading and trailing spaces removed. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1):

When we have a sort of some repetitive patterns, we can iterate over that. In your case it is `---`

So we can solve it this way ...

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file=$(<"$1");

# read-only numeric value 
declare -ir chunk_max=$(grep -c '\-\-\-'  <<< "$file");

for ((index=0; index < $chunk_max; ++index )); do
    chunk="${file%%---*}";
    file="${file#*---}";
    echo "chunk[ $index ]";
    echo "$chunk";
done
```

The script:

- count how many `---` we have
- loop up to **chunk_max**
- remove anything up to first **chunk** | right side match
- update the **file** by removing *first chunk* we extracted | left side match

#### output

```bash
chunk[ 0 ]
>some multiline-
>text

chunk[ 1 ]

>in multiple chunks (this one for instance is the second of this sample)

chunk[ 2 ]

>Their number, sizes and content are irregular

chunk[ 3 ]

>they can't
>be known in
>advance

chunk[ 4 ]

>And they'll contain pretty much any char whatsoever known or unknown in the universe
>like //\n/...
```

Some bug fixes

- if a line contains `---` , grep will fail
- removing newlines before or after each chunk

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file=$(<"$1");

# only a single line starts end ends with ---
declare -ir chunk_max=$(grep -c '^\-\-\-$'  <<< "$file");

for ((index=0; index < $chunk_max; ++index )); do
    # from the end, delete everything up to "\n----"
    chunk="${file%%$'\n'---*}";

    # from the beginning, delete everything up to "---\n"
    file="${file#*---$'\n'}";

    # print
    echo "chunk[ $index ]";
    echo "$chunk";
done
```

#### output

```bash
chunk[ 0 ]
>some multiline-
>text
chunk[ 1 ]
>in multiple chunks (this one for instance is the second of this sample)
chunk[ 2 ]
>Their number, sizes and content are irregular
chunk[ 3 ]
>they can't
>be known in
>advance
chunk[ 4 ]
>And they'll contain pretty much any char whatsoever known or unknown in the universe
>like //\n/...
```

---

NOTE

- `$'...'` treat the value as a special character so `$'\n'` means it is a newline not `\` + `n`
- `${VAR%%PATTERN}` match from right side and delete
- `${VAR##PATTERN}` match from left side and delete

Comment: Hello, this uses a for and is very close to what I'm looking for (which may not exist).

Only problem is it fails if one of the chunks contains "---" I fixed it by changing the grepped pattern to `^\-\-\-$` and the substitutions to `${file%%[$'\n']---[$'\n']*}` and `${file#*[$'\n']---[$'\n']}`

I'm just not really sure what's the `[$'\n']` syntax exactly, that's some unexplained copy paste I found that worked and which's name I don't know so I cant find a proper doc about it ...

Comment: @Ar3s Thanks mentioning those bugs, I fixed them